# Restructuring data inside of Mongo or out?

Tags: mongodb

I have some simple transaction-style data in a flat format like the following:

```
{
    'giver': 'Alexandra',
    'receiver': 'Julie',
    'amount': 20,
    'year_given': 2015
}
```

There can be multiple entries for any 'giver' or 'receiver'.

I am mostly querying this data based on the giver field, and then split up by year. So, I would like to speed up these queries.

I'm fairly new to Mongo so I'm not sure which of the following methods would be the best course of action:

**1. Restructure the data into the format:**

```
{
    'giver': 'Alexandra',
    'transactions': {
        '2015': [
            {
                'receiver': 'Julie',
                'amount': 20
            },
        ...
        ],
        '2014': ...,
        ...
    }
}
```

This makes me the most sense to me. We place all transactions into subdocuments of a person rather than having transactions all over the collection. It provides the data in the form I query it by the most, so it should be fast to query by 'giver' and then 'transactions.year'

I'm unsure if restructuring data like this is possible inside of mongo or if I should export it and modify it outside of mongo via some programming language.

**2. Simply index by 'giver'**

This doesn't quite match the way I'm querying this data (by 'giver' then 'year'), but it could be fast enough to do what I'm looking for. It's simple within mongo to do, and doesn't require restructuring of the data.

How should I go about adjusting my database to make my queries faster? And which way is the 'Mongo way'?